# Compare 2 images using C#

Tags: c#

Can we compare 2 images of different resolutions and colour.

Comment: Sure... scale them down to the same resolution and then "compare" them... whatever that means.

Comment: when I read that, I thought you were a troll making fun of the OP... and then I realized you were the OP. \*face palm\*

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be done. 
have a look at the below link to find if it helps ur requirment if not atleast should be useful for startup for ur req

[Image Comparison using C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prathore/ImageComparison01022009050404AM/ImageComparison.aspx)